# @media section not responding

Tags: css, media

i have this in media.css

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {

section {
    width: 1450px;
}    

div {
    width: 700px;
}

}
```

then i have in main css

```
@import "media.css";

section {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
padding: 1 0 20 0;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 50px;
width:700px;
}

div {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
margin: 20 10 0 10;
border-radius: 50px;
padding: 10 10 20 10;
}
```

ween i resize the window the div grow like it should but the section stays equal.. 
i have it in html like this

```
<section>
<div> 
</div>
</section>
```

so why is the section not respondig?

**i may add that i made a fiddle but its working fine.. so maybe its a software problem???? i restarted everithing and its the same.. i am usig brackets**

i made here a *fake fiddle* with the prtscrn

[image: everithing ok here]

[image: section not changing]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/freakhealer/qhuuuxgc/ this is the fiddle, its working fine (no styling but its expanding)

Answer (score 2):

This is totally wrong:

```
div {
    width: 700px;
    display: inline;
}
```

You **cannot** set width to `inline` elements. Either change it to `inline-block` or remove it to be `block`.

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer What did you change to? Change it to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: i just take it out, i tried to change to inline-block but the problem its not solved so i just take it out.. i try also the section display but its not normal, did you see the image ?

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer Actually you **need** to put `display: inline-block`, nothing else. Try that.

Comment: i tried in both right know, as i said, and its not solving.. actually just change that the section its not centered,

Answer (score 1):

Please give section class name. Then it will work. like class="my_section". css: .my_section{width:1440px}

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your `media.css` is being read before `main.css`. The most recent declaration is being used if all selectors have the same specificity. The reason the `div` gets a `width` is because you haven't declared one in `main.css`, which you have with `section`.

[**See my example here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mex47eqj/1/) (minimize the output window to see that it works).

Comment: i changed the inport for the end of css and its the same but the width of section have to be set and div not because its relative.. i want it to make 2 div if its full window, and 1 if half.. 
and what i said its the div its respondig to the media, section not at all..

Comment: I've added an example. If you minimize the output window you'll see that it changes color and width.

Comment: thanks for trying but thats the simple media.. my problem is that its not responding, i added fotos in because the fiddle its working fine with my code,